# Fatal error for category archives

Tags: errors

When entering the blog and clicking on any of the categories, an error appears.

> There was a fatal error with this site.
>
> Learn more about WordPress troubleshooting.

When using the query monitor tool, I encountered an error

> There was a fatal error with this site.
>
> Learn more about WordPress troubleshooting.

I discovered that when the template is changed, the problem is solved and the categories work.

Comment: Check your server log file to find out what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

for make sure about the problems, would you like to show us about the errors by adding below code in your wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

be better if you give web console message to when accessed the error category/url.

Comment: After setting this code, where does the problem code appear?

Comment: just revisit last url you get the error message

**There was a fatal error with this site.
Learn more about WordPress troubleshooting.**

Comment: Thank you very much